# Is it possible to replace Android N's ART with Android M's?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-source, android-7.0-nougat, xposed

In AOSP 7 source tree, Is it be possible to use Android 6's `art/` instead of the original Android 7's `art/`?

I don't ever recall having seen such replacements before, but out of curisity is it possible? You may ask me why? The answer is all about [xposed](/questions/tagged/xposed). Xposed doesn't currently support Android N yet, but works pretty good on M. So, my question would be: Is replacing N's ART with M's ART an option to enable Xposed on N? If the answer is no, please let me know the why.

If this question is off-topic here, kindly tell me to move it to the SO's sister android.SX.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. Nougat internals are different than Marshmallow ones, so you can't simply get some system component from older Android and replace it.

Comment: I'd rather prefer a more _technical_ answer than one you've provided.